# Send image + data in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, form-data

I need to send an image and data in my API request. How can I do the same with JMeter? Please help me out. I have done the following method but it didn't work

````
content-disposition: form-data; name="key1"
value1

--boundary
content-disposition: form-data; name="key2"

value2
--boundary
content-disposition: form-data; name="key3"

value3
--boundary
content-disposition: form-data; name="image1"; filename="file.jpg"
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
--boundary

$binarydata
--boundary--```
````

Answer (score 0):

1. Provide "data" using "Parameters" tab of the HTTP Request sampler:

   [image]
2. Provide "image" using "Files upload" tab of the HTTP Request sampler:

   [image]
3. Tick "Use multipart/form-data" box

Demo:

[image]

Going forward if you have doubts with regards to proper HTTP Request sampler configuration be aware that you can just record the request using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder.](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) Just make sure that the file(s) you're uploading are present in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation during recording otherwise the capture will fail.

More information: [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter)

Comment: I have tried the same method but I am getting "{"detail":"JSON parse error - 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 720: invalid start byte"}" error.

Comment: Dmitri, Please help.